# Bash: "xargs cat", adding newlines after each file

Tags: bash, xargs, cat

I'm using a few commands to *cat* a few files, like this:

```
 cat somefile | grep example | awk -F '"' '{ print $2 }' | xargs cat
```

It nearly works, but my issue is that I'd like to add a newline after each file.

Can this be done in a one liner?

(surely I can create a new script or a function that does *cat* and then *echo -n* but I was wondering if this could be solved in another way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat somefile | grep example | awk -F '"' '{ print $2 }' | while read file; do cat $file; echo ""; done
```

Comment: excellent :)   (I can only accept the answer in 7 minutes, will keep the tab open :)

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ it may be even faster (depending on your system):

```
cat somefile | grep example | awk -F '"' '{ print $2 }' | parallel "cat {}; echo"
```

Answer (score 0):

awk -F '"' '/example/{ system("cat " $2 };printf "\n"}' somefile